# Extend docker run time out

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am running a docker image on a Windows PC using the following operation:

1. I open the Docker Desktop app.
2. In a git bash window in the code (Python if it matters) directory I run `docker build -t estimate_something -f Dockerfile .`
3. In another regular terminal in the code directory I run `docker-compose run -p 9000:8080 -e MY_ENV_VAR="VERY_IMPORTANT_VAR" something_estimation`
4. In the git bash window I run  `curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9000/2015-03-31/functions/function/invocations" -d @some_input.json`

Now, no matter what I have tried the docker times out after 5 minutes.
Is it possible to extend this time out?

Comment: I dont get it, The docker compose work for five min then stop ? I am not sure but i dont get the need of extending the timeout  in this scenario.

Comment: @George the computation performed by the code takes much more than 5 minutes

Comment: Good, Python with flask or Django ? I think your issue is there not in the docker.

Comment: @George None of them, this is a pure mathematical algorithm. What velse could it be besides the docker?

Comment: its 99% not the docker issue, either the webserver or the curl command limitation.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like it's `curl` that times out. The default is 5 minutes which is what you're seeing.

You can set the curl timeout with the `-m` option, followed by the number of seconds you want it to be.

So to get a 10 minute timeout, you'd do

```
curl -XPOST -m 600 "http://localhost:9000/2015-03-31/functions/function/invocations" -d @some_input.json
```

Comment: sorry, but adding the `-m 600` option didn't change anything, still getting `sk timed out after 300.00 seconds`